# How to reflect changing rankings instantly?

Tags: php, html, css, sorting, web

Basically what's going on is I've been trying to develop a ratings system that stores users total ratings and also displays the items in order based on their ratings.  But now I ran into a bug that only changes the ratings/display after rating twice as opposed to obviously just once.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
include ("sql.php");

function getTotal($name) {
$query = "SELECT total FROM items WHERE name = '$name'";
// echo $query;
// echo "<br />";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
return $row[0];
}



display();
function display($items) {
    $video = getTotal(video);
    // echo "video total: ".$video;
    // echo "<br />";
    $Music = getTotal(Music);
    // echo "Music total: ".$Music;
    // echo "<br />";
    $football = getTotal(football);
    // echo "football total: ".$football;
    // echo "<br />";

    $items = array($video => 'video', $Music => 'Music', $football=>'football');
    // echo "<br />";
    krsort($items);
    // print_r($items);
foreach ($items as $key => $val) {
    print ("<form method = 'post'>
    $val
    <button name ='upvote' type = 'submit' value ='$val' />Upvote</button>
    <button name ='downvote' type ='submit' value ='$val' />Downvote</button>
    </form> TOTAL: ".$key."
        ");
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['upvote']) || isset($_POST['downvote'])) {

$ip = 23;
//$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_footballDR']);

if ($_POST['upvote'] != null) {
$item = $_REQUEST['upvote'];
}
else {
$item = $_REQUEST['downvote'];
}

//see if person has voted before, for this item
$q = "SELECT count(*) FROM tracker".$item." WHERE ip = $ip";
$check = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($check);
$bool = ($row[0] > 0);

    if (!$bool) {
        echo "User has not voted before for this item <br />";

    }

    else {
        echo "user has voted for this item before";
        //then the user has voted before
        //row[0] = ip, row[1] = value
        $d = "SELECT * FROM tracker".$item." WHERE ip = '$ip'";
        $e = mysql_query($d);
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($e);
        $value = -$row[1];
        echo "<br /> value: ".$value;
        $qry = "UPDATE items SET total = total + $value WHERE name = '$item'";
        echo "<br /> qry: ".$qry;
        $result = mysql_query($qry);

        if (!$result) {
            echo "problem with result".mysql_error();

        }


        $q = "DELETE FROM tracker".$item." WHERE ip = '$ip'";
        echo "<br /> Delete query".$q; 
        $r = mysql_query($q);
        if (!$r) {
            echo "problem with r".mysql_error();
        }

    }



if ($item == $_POST['upvote']) {
    echo "<br /> item has been upvoted";
    $qry = "UPDATE items SET total = total + 1 WHERE name = '$item'";
    echo "<br /> qry: ".$qry;
    mysql_query($qry);

//also get the ip footballdress and footballd to the who's voted table
    $d = "INSERT INTO tracker".$item." VALUES ('$ip', '1')";
    mysql_query($d);
    }

elseif ($item == $_POST['downvote']) {
    echo "<br /> item has been downvoted";
    $qry = "UPDATE items SET total = total - 1 WHERE name = '$item'";
    mysql_query($qry);

//also get the ip footballdress and footballd to the who's voted table
    $d = "INSERT INTO tracker".$item." VALUES ('$ip', '-1')";
    mysql_query($d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have detailed some mistakes there:

1. Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions
2. Remember to clean any input in SQL to prevent [SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
3. Always check the variable from the `queries`

   $check = query($sql);
   if (!$check) {
       // show or return an error message if needed
   }
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($check);
4. Use `try` and `catch` block to prevent unmanaged exceptions
5. To show the new updated vote you can retrieve the votes after being updated from the table

Comment: thanks, I appreciate all the info so far. But what exactly do you mean by retrieve the votes after being updated? I thought maybe a jquery function to update it when the form is submitted, but for some bizarre reason the text I was testing will stay up for a second then disappear. This is what I added script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#form').submit(function(){
  $('#form').append('<p>Some text</p>');
 });
})

Comment: I mean, after you update the vote counter you can `SELECT FROM` again from the table